# Interop Excel : PivotTable.RefreshTable() throws exception

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I am trying to refresh my PivotTable which has been already rendered. Below is the code to refresh :

```
Excel.PivotTables pivotTables = worksheet.PivotTables();
Excel.PivotTable pvt = pivotTables.Cast<Excel.PivotTable>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == pivotTableName);
pvt.RefreshTable(); //throws exception
```

I am getting below exception:

> This command requires at least two rows of source data. You cannot use the command on a selection in only one row. Try the following:
>
> • If you're using an advanced filter, select a range of cells that contains at least two rows of data. Then click the Advanced Filter command again.
>
> • If you're creating a PivotTable report or PivotChart report, type a cell reference or select a range that includes at least two rows of data.

I am able to understand that the sourcedata gets corrupted or modified, but not able to reach the solution.
Any help or suggestion would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Check the DataSource for the PivotTable and make sure that it has at least 2 rows of data prior to calling the Refresh.

Comment: Thanks @FrankBall, you are right. I have used NamedRange for source data and it changes to single row whenever I clear the data. To fix it, I have used Cell Address instead of NamedRange

Comment: Keep in mind that using a static address has it's own drawbacks.  Using a Table (List Object) for your data source is the safest way to go.  A Table resizes to the data present and allows you to check the row count with great ease.  It's one of the most under-appreciated tools in Excel.

Comment: sure I will take note of it. Thanks